# How to turn off code generation in Simulink? (function is not supported for standalone code generation)

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink, matlab-coder

I am creating a simulation which I will port to another language myself. So I don't need to use code generation capabilities of Simulink. How to turn it's attempts to allow code generation OFF?

For example, I have the following code inside `MATLAB Function` block:

```
function OutImage = ResizeCropPad(InImage, Width, Height)
%#codegen

    %coder.extrinsic('imresize');

    % resizing to defined height
    scale = Height/size(InImage,1);
    InImage = imresize(InImage, scale);

    % cropping to defined width
    if Width<size(InImage,2)
        padarray(InImage, [0 size(InImage,2)-Width], 0, 'both');
    elseif Width>size(InImage,2)
        b = floor((Width-size(InImage,2))/2);
        InImage = InImage(:,b:b+Width-1,:);
    end

    OutImage = InImage;
```

and it gives an error

> The function 'imresize' is not supported for standalone code
>   generation. See the documentation for coder.extrinsic to learn how you
>   can use this function in simulation.

If I uncomment `coder.extrinsic('imresize')` line I get new error

> Expected either a logical, char, int, fi, single, or double. Found an
>   mxArray. MxArrays are returned from calls to the MATLAB interpreter
>   and are not supported inside expressions. They may only be used on the
>   right-hand side of assignments and as arguments to extrinsic
>   functions.

Addressing line 11, with `if`.

Why? Is it possible to completely disable code generation, for example at model level?

Comment: In the context of using a MATLAB Function block you cannot turn the code generation off.  The way that block works is to convert the m-code into c-code (or wrap anything defined as code.extrinsic in c-code) and run that compiled code as part of the simulation.  It has nothing to do with code generation for the whole model (as would occur if you used Simulink Coder rather than doing it yourself).

Answer (score 3):

You need to uncomment the `coder.extrinsic('imresize');` line and declare/initialise the `InImage` variable before calling the `imresize` function. See [Converting mxArrays to Known Types](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/calling-matlab-functions.html#bq1h2z9-47) for more info.

**EDIT following discussion in the comments**:

The following should work:

```
function OutImage = ResizeCropPad(InImage, Width, Height)
%#codegen

    coder.extrinsic('imresize');

    % resizing to defined height
    scale = Height/size(InImage,1);
    OutImage = InImage;
    OutImage = imresize(InImage, scale);

    % cropping to defined width
    if Width<size(OutImage,2)
        padarray(OutImage, [0 size(OutImage,2)-Width], 0, 'both');
    elseif Width>size(OutImage,2)
        b = floor((Width-size(outImage,2))/2);
        OutImage = OutImage(:,b:b+Width-1,:);
    end
```

Comment: Also see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/13297-subscripting-into-an-mxarray

Comment: Since `InImage` is input parameter of a function, doesn't this mean that it is already initialized before calling of `imresize`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. You probably want to use another variable rather than overwrite the input when calling `imresize`. Why not use `OutImage` straight away rather than wait until the end of the function? You could initialise it by `OutImage = InImage` before calling the `imresize` function.